# Firebase. Сделать значение переменной

Tags: java, android, firebase, переменные

Как значение в базе данных Firebase сделать переменной в андроид чтобы сравнить значения?

Если делать так

```
DatabaseReference db = mMessageDatabaseReference.child("people").child(user.getUid()).child("number");

if(db == 0) {
   ...
```

подчеркивает `(db == 0)`.

Что я не так сделал?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно официальной документации (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) вы должны сделать так:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ValueEventListener valueListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int peopleNumber = dataSnapshot.child("people").child(user.getUid()).child("number").getValue(Integer.class);
        if (peopleNumber == 0){
          //do something
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(valueListener);
```

Так же вы можете использовать метод `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` который выполниться только раз, что удобно при единичных запросах к базе данных.

Comment: а можно ли как то проверить существует ли значение вообще? int peopleNumber = dataSnapshot.child("people").child(user.getUid()).child("number").getValue(Integer.class);

Comment: еще выдает ошибку  Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int